# App review for login mechanism requires pre-login org selection

Tags: app-store-connect, google-play-console

I'm developing a mobile app that requires users to select an org before proceeding to the login screen. Users can belong to any org, so email login alone wouldn't suffice. Here's the flow:

- User selects an org by enter the org id or pick it from a list of recently selected orgs on launch.
- User enters their email and password to log in.
- App configures itself based on the chosen org (API endpoint, settings).

My questions:

- **Are there any known issues with this approach regarding Apple App Store or Google Play Store review guidelines?** (Specifically concerning requiring org selection before login)
- **Has anyone had experience submitting apps with similar login flows?** If so, did you encounter any difficulties during the app review process on either platform (Apple or Google)?

I'd appreciate any insights or advice from the community!

I haven't tried to submit the app yet.